# Creating partial class for wpf functions and events

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, partial-classes

I've a WPF program which it's MainWindows.xaml.cs has many functions and events. I want to make it more readable so I moved some of the functions and events in a separate class named "partialClassMainWindow.cs". I moved all button events to it. now when I click on a button it must go to button_Click function in partialClassMainWindow but a new funciton is created in MainWindows.xaml.cs.

how can I prevent it?

for example consider this simple program:

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication3
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //moved to partialClassMainWindow:
        //private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        //{

        //}
    }
}
```

partialClassMainWindow.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication3
{
    public partial class MainWindow:Window
    {
        public void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = "Hello World";

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The creators of WPF favored MVVM and the command pattern as their tools, so if you want to do code-behind you will probably not get that level of support. Do yourself a favor and learn MVVM and the command pattern, it will make working with WPF a *lot* easier.

Comment: As stated above, instead of using `partial class` use `ViewModel` and `Commands`

Comment: @XAMlMAX can you post the use of ViewModel and Commands for the program mentioned above?

Comment: [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/126249/MVVM-Pattern-in-WPF-A-Simple-Tutorial-for-Absolute) is a "brilliant" example for you to learn from. HTH

Answer (score 1):

Don't think that you can avoid it. It looks like Visual studio just checks the code behind file and not any other files with more partial code. But the other guys are right MVVM is the way to go and normally you have little or none code behind. Only typical view stuff you would handle there, all the business logic goes into the viewmodel.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx

Is a good place to start reading about MVVM.